# Running two UIAlertController in sequence

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 `UIAlertController` in sequence. What I want is that after showing the 1º, it will only show the second if the user click one of the 2 options. Right now shows the 1º `UIAlertController` and dont show the second one.

The code is BIG, but I have commented those 2 blocks of `UIAlertControllers` named: `Block1` and `Block2`

How can I do that?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let pratos = queryArray[indexPath.row] as PFObject

    var confirmar = 0

    //BLOCK1
    //Pergunta o tipo de entrega
    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Selecione o método de entrega", message: "", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
    }

    actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let takePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Away", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        confirmar = 1

    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(takePictureAction)

    let choosePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Entrega ao domicílio", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        confirmar = 2
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(choosePictureAction)


    self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    println("Hello")

    //BLOCK2
    if confirmar == 1 || confirmar == 2 {

        //Confirma se pretende comprar
    var loginTextField: UITextField?
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Deseja continuar?", message: "A sua encomenda será processada.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    var preco = pratos.objectForKey("Preco") as! String
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Comprar \(preco)€" , style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in


        var Transacao = PFObject(className:"Transacao")
        Transacao["pointerUser"] = PFUser.currentUser()
        Transacao["pointerRestaurante"] = self.restauranteRow
        Transacao["pointerProduto"] = pratos
        Transacao["entrega"] = confirmar
        Transacao.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("compraEfectuada", sender: self)

            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
        }




    })
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
        println("Cancel Button Pressed")
    }
    alertController.addAction(ok)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)

        presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment both `UIAlertController`'s are created in the function from the tableview. This function gets triggered by the tableview delegate when the user clicks on it. There is no way the second one can ever be created because the entire function is executed before the first alert controller is presented. So your `if` statement will always be false.

Put the second `UIAlertController` in a separate function. Instead of setting `confirmer` to 1 or 2, trigger the corresponding function. Then it will work.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    //BLOCK1
    //Pergunta o tipo de entrega
    alertOne()

}

func alertOne() {
    //BLOCK1
    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Selecione o método de entrega", message: "", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
    }

    actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let takePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Away", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        alertTwo(1)

    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(takePictureAction)

    let choosePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Entrega ao domicílio", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
        alertTwo(2)
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(choosePictureAction)


    self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func alertTwo(confirmar:Int) {
    //BLOCK2

    let pratos = queryArray[indexPath.row] as PFObject

    //Confirma se pretende comprar
    var loginTextField: UITextField?
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Deseja continuar?", message: "A sua encomenda será processada.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    var preco = pratos.objectForKey("Preco") as! String
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Comprar \(preco)€" , style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in


        var Transacao = PFObject(className:"Transacao")
        Transacao["pointerUser"] = PFUser.currentUser()
        Transacao["pointerRestaurante"] = self.restauranteRow
        Transacao["pointerProduto"] = pratos
        Transacao["entrega"] = confirmar
        Transacao.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("compraEfectuada", sender: self)

            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
            }
        }




    })
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
        println("Cancel Button Pressed")
    }
    alertController.addAction(ok)
    alertController.addAction(cancel)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: It works now :)

But the 'performSegueWithIdentifier' now don't work. Any idea?

Comment: I am guessing `Transacao.saveInBackgroundWithBlock` never returns true. No idea why. Place something like `print("failed to save in background")` in the `else` statement.

Comment: Just a bit of advice. Try to code in english. Especially for SO. When you name your functions/variables/classes their names also say something about their function. Not being able to interpret these makes it harder to help.

Comment: It doesnt return, but writes into Parse. Before this solution, this was working, there is something wrong now, idk. You are right about code in english, will do!

Comment: `Transacao.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in` That is a function which will return true when finished successfully. Hence the `success:Bool` So placing a breakpoint or a `print()` in the `else` part will tell you what happened there. Just to be complete also place one in the `if` part. Then you know if the  `saveInBackgroundWithBlock ` failed or the segue failed.

Comment: Segue failed. It was working before, but i've done the segue all over again and it doesnt work. Maybe the 'sender:' have to be different now?

Comment: Working now. Dont know why... Thank you for being helpful :)